# Spring - Getting domain name in use

Tags: spring-mvc, url

I have a Spring application running that uses SpringMVC and EclipseLink.

This application works well with multiple top level domains at the same point, for example you can access:

```
http://www.foo.com/user/list
http://www.anotherdomain.com/user/list
http://www.company.com/user/list
```

But now I need to load a customized design for each domain, so I need to identify what is the domain that's accessing.

I'll need to implement a class that would set views path, etc.

Anyone knows a good solution for this?

Comment: Do you want to access it in jsp?

Comment: No, I need to access in a java file class that will be used to resolve views path, etc.

Answer (score 8):

Get it from Header "Host". In Spring

- you [can try](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestHeader.html) `@RequestHeader String host` in controller method as parameter.

OR

- get it [from](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getHeader(java.lang.String)) `HttpServletRequest.getHeader("host")`

Comment: But the host will not be always the same?

Comment: return views after inspecting Host

Comment: Yes, but my question is , the host will not be always the same independ that domain name?

Comment: Braj, please ignore my question. I was testing now and works. I will try to get this outside controller now. (A java util class).

Comment: There's only one secure way of getting it. Don't rely on headers because clients can always modify then. The best and most secure option is to configure the name in your properties.

Comment: Will request actually reach the server if host header is modified?

Comment: @Klesun it will as long as it's directed to the right IP. Might not go through any reverse proxy or webserver depending on how they are set up.